# How to create a matrix with a new List of Color

Tags: vb.net

Basically, what I want to do is this:

```
Dim colors1(100, 100) As New List(Of Color)
```

I need to create a matrix with the `New List(Of Color)`.

I will explain better...

I want to read all the colors of the pixels of my image, and usualy i would do that by reading line by line.
But that is not the case.
I divide the image in 8x8 squares and i want create an matrix(whit position of square)and the List(Of Color)(whit the colors of that square) that says all the colors of each square. Infortunaly when i try do this `Dim colors1(100,100) as List(Of Color)`the program break.

Comment: What about a [multi-dimensional array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d2de1t93(v=vs.90).aspx) of Color?

Comment: I tryed that but it requires to have the `New` or will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```css
        Dim colors1 As New List(Of List(Of Color))
        For i As Integer = 0 To 99
            Dim newColors As New List(Of Color)
            colors1.Add(newColors)
            For j As Integer = 0 To 99
                newColors.Add(New Color)
            Next
        Next​
```

Comment: i tryed it and didnt worked for m, but thx that 'New List(Of List(Of Color))' my be the soluction

Comment: What didn't work for you here?  I just tested and if you want a list, this is a really cool way to do it.  Once you run that code, you can assign colors to the list like colors1(73)(33) = Color.Purple and then you can use the list like TextBox1.BackColor = colors1(73)(33) .  I believe that should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, are you wanting to use an `Array` or a `List` for this?

If you want a fixed 100x100 matrix then you should use a 2D `Array` since arrays are fixed size.

If you're happy to use a fixed 100x100 2D `Array`, you can declare it like:

```
Dim colors1(100, 100) As Color
```

Set it like this:

```
colors1(5, 2) = Color.Aqua
```

And then use it like this:

```
' Sets the textbox background color to Aqua
TextBox1.BackColor = colors1(5, 2)
```

Does that achieve what you're trying to do?  Or did you need the List for another reason?

Comment: i realy need the list becasue (x,y) is the cordinaltes of the block and lthe list have all the colors that exist on that  block

Comment: That's okay.  You should be able to use jdweng's solution then.